# Force `sort` to ignore file extensions when sorting `find` output by file name

Tags: bash, find, ls, sort

Is there an easy way to force `sort` to ignore file extensions when sorting `find` output by file name? I mean without extra scripting.

Comment: Please give an example `find` command that you are trying to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean.

But given a directory

```
$ ls
bar.txt  foo.abc  foo.txt
$
```

You can sort by just the name, stripping the extension, as below

```
$ find . -type f | sort -k 2,2 -t. -u
./bar.txt
./foo.txt
$
```

As ever, an example of input together with desired output would help greatly.

Comment: Why does this `find . -type f | sort -k2 -t. -u` give different result? Why `2,2` is passed?